# Java: Terminating the while loop after pressing "Q" key

Tags: java

I have this following java program which is working fine without while loop, but I want to run the execution until user pressed Q key from the keyboard.

So What condition should be put in while loop which breaks the loop?

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.Q;

public class BinaryToDecimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
        while(kbhit() != Q){
            System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
            try{          
                String n = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(n,2));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Not a binary number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Comment: I know kbhit() in C language, but don't know in java

Comment: Question is unclear until you show that method

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you want to know, how you can read a keyboard input?

Comment: what condition should be put in while loop which breaks the loop?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use KeyEvent within a console application as there's no keyboard listener defined.

Try a do-while loop to watch for an input of the letter q. And you should compare strings using equals method

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        
    String n;
    System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
    do {
        try{          
            n = in.nextLine();
            // break early 
            if (n.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) break;
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(n,2));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not a binary number");
        }
        // Prompt again 
        System.out.print("Input binary number: ");
    } while(!n.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
```

Comment: The output is looking same whether we put " if " statement in the try block. Let me know if it reduces the unnecessary overhead or not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Obviously you'd like to prevent parsing letter q as an integer

Comment: In try block,  "if (n.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) break;" Will it reduces the execution time or performance time? In case if user's input is "q" in the beginning.

Comment: Of course it adds execution time, it's another statement. But it's negligible. Why do you care about performance of such simple code?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public class BinaryToDecimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = in.nextLine();
        while(!"q".equalsIgnoreCase(line.trim())){
            try{
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(line,2));
                System.out.print("Input next binary number: ");          
                line = in.nextLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Not a binary number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are prompting for input before "Input first binary number", which might not be obvious

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! fixed.